# How to use a declare statement to update a table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this Declare Statement

```
declare @ReferralLevelData table([Type of Contact] varchar(10));
insert into @ReferralLevelData values ('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel'),('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel'),('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel');

select (row_number() over (order by [Type of Contact]) % 3) +1 as [Referral ID]
    ,[Type of Contact]
from @ReferralLevelData 
order by [Referral ID]
        ,[Type of Contact];
```

It does not insert into the table so i feel this is not working as expect, i.e it doesn't modify the table.

If it did work I was hoping to modify the statement to make it update.

At the moment the table just prints this result

```
1   f2f
1   nf2f
1   Travel
2   f2f
2   nf2f
2   Travel
3   f2f
3   nf2f
3   Travel
```

**EDIT**:
I want TO Update the table to enter recurring data in groups of three.

I have a table of data, it is duplicated twice in the same table to make three sets.

Its "ReferenceID" is the primary key, i want to in a way group the 3 same ReferenceID's and inject these three values "f2f" "NF2F" "Travel" into the row called "Type" in any order but ensure that each ReferenceID only has one of those values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want... Do you think, that the `SELECT` should somehow change your declared table variable? That it should add a new column `[Referral ID]` to your table? This table has got one single column. The `SELECT` won't change this... But you might create a new temp-table by using `INTO #newTempTable` right before the `from`. Then you can use `SELECT * FROM #newTempTable` to see the persisted result... Please clearify your needs...

Comment: The [Referral ID] is already in the table, so i want to use that and update data into the [Type of Contact] which is already there

Comment: Sorry, again not clear: This part `declare @ReferralLevelData table([Type of Contact] varchar(10));` will declare a table variable with one single column of type `varchar(10)`. The `SELECT` will return a *result set* where the `[Referral ID]` is computed *on-the-fly* by `ROW_NUMBER()`, but this was never part of any table...

Comment: @Shnugo I have updated my question to add some clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the following?

```
declare @ReferralLevelData table(
    [Referral ID] int,
    [Type of Contact] varchar(10)
  );

insert into @ReferralLevelData([Referral ID],[Type of Contact])
select
  (row_number() over (order by [Type of Contact]) % 3) +1 as [Referral ID]
  ,[Type of Contact]
from
  (
    values ('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel'),('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel'),('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel')
  ) v([Type of Contact]);
```

If it suits you then you also can use the next query to generate data:

```
select r.[Referral ID],ct.[Type of Contact]
from
  (
    values ('f2f'),('nf2f'),('Travel')
  ) ct([Type of Contact])
cross join
  (
    values (1),(2),(3)
  ) r([Referral ID]);
```